# Call function with multiple arguments based on conditional statement

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

Title says it all I have the following function :

```
var foo = function(arg1, arg2,arg3) {
    // code
}
```

I want to do something like :

```
foo('bar', (x == true ? arg2, arg3 : arg2,arg3))
```

But I get hit with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,` what is the right syntax to do something like this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go with readability as JCOC611 said...

Yet, the "right" way is using .apply():

```
foo.apply(this, (x == true ? [arg1, arg2, arg3] : [arg1 ,arg2, arg3]))
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is worth it to save a few characters. It's much more valuable to have readable code. Just get a minifier/uglyfier, and do this:

```
if(x === true){
   foo('bar', arg2, arg3);
}else{
   foo('bar', arg2, arg3);
}
```

Comment: I partially disagree with the solution, when there is a specific method (apply) for a function,  we should use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = function(arg1, arg2,arg3) {
    console.log(arguments)
}
var x = false;
var args = [];
args.push('bar');
x == true ? (function(){args.push('arg2'); args.push('arg3')})() : args.push('arg2');
console.log(args)
foo.apply(this,args)
```

There are two methods to pass the `variable` no of arguments to the function.

1. [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)
2. [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Use either one as per your need.